# MKMapView: There A Way To Detect Whether Satellite Imagery Has Loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

Pretty simple question, when using an MKMapView (MapKit), and you're using MKMapTypeSatellite, sometimes, especially in rural areas, you can zoom in further than the available satellite imagery.  Is there any way to detect whether the imagery is available, so you can adjust the zoom level or change to MKMapTypeStandard or something?